# Não estou conseguindo fazer o bind com imagem

Tags: vue.js-2

Alguém saberia me explicar o motivo de não estar conseguindo renderizar a imagem na tela. Estou utilizando o **Vue-cli** e a imagem está na pasta **assets** dentro da pasta **src** normal, mas quando chamo ela no template não carrega. Já tentei assim: **`./assets/produto.png`**,  assim: **`../assets/produto.png`**, assim: **`src/assets/produto.png`**. Mas sem sucesso!

**Template:**

```
<div>
  <img :src="imagem" :alt="alt">
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
data () {
  return {
    imagem: './assets/produto.png',
    alt: 'Imagens dos produtos.'
  }
}
```

Comment: Algum erro no chrome tools?

Comment: @HiagoSouza Cara nenhum.

Comment: Ao inspecionar elemento qual o conteúdo apresentado na tag img?

Comment: Pode postar o código completo com o seu controller?

Comment: @HiagoSouza Cara consegui resolver aqui, o vue-cli cria uma pasta **assets** e joga as imagens dentro dela, só que tbm cria uma outra pasta chamada **static**  no mesmo nível da assets e as imagens tem que ser inseridas nesta pasta static.

Comment: Topp! Isso ai, coloque a solução como resposta para a comunidade. Abraço.

Comment: Tentou assim? `imagem: '~assets/produto.png'`

Comment: @Marconi Assim tbm não foi man. Comigo só funcionou tirando as imagens da pasta assets e colocando na pasta static mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Pessoal para quem tiver o mesmo problema é só colocar as imagens dentro da pasta **`static`** que é criada pelo vue-cli no mesmo nível da pasta **assets**.

**Template:**

```
<div>
  <img :src="imagem" :alt="alt">
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
data () {
  return {
    imagem: './static/produto.png',
    alt: 'Imagens dos produtos.'
  }
}
```